In my Tex file, this type of error show. So what i do to resolve it
Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/txr/bx/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/txr/bx/n on input line 29.


Welcome to TeX.SE, please post MWE of your code, then only you can get the suitable suggestion for your requirement, from your post, it's very odd to understand what the error

Note those are not errors. But info. Though I'd probably recommend using \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} if you're using pdflatex here. As OT1 is probably not worth it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why do you claim that the entries in the log file report errors? Please edit your query to post the preamble of your LaTeX document.

Post your code from \documentclass to \end{document} and please refer https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that for more details

No error at all. You're using txfonts and LaTeX just informs you that the default assignments for math fonts are overridden by the package.
The key is LaTeX Font Info. Messages in the log file can be labeled
Info (just information), Warning (something to be taken seriously) or Error (which must be dealt with).
By the way, you shouldn't use txfonts, but
\usepackage{newtx}

instead, because the fonts provided by txfonts have awkward spacing and kernings.
